# How to mimic a webpage search on python?

Tags: python-3.x

I created a function called def createPageDict(d) that outputs a dictionary of made up webpages and the associated words on each web page. For example, when createPageDict(d) is called, the following is produced:

```
{'cat': {'www.page0.com', 'www.page1.com', 'www.page2.com'},
 'dog': {'www.page0.com', 'www.page1.com'},
 'fish': {'www.page0.com', 'www.page2.com'},
 'frog': {'www.page1.com'},
 'rat': {'www.page1.com', 'www.page2.com'},
 'goat': {'www.page2.com'}}
```

Now, I have to create another function called search Pages() that should return the set of all the webpages that all the words appear on.  For example, cat and dog appear on page0 and page1, but not on page2.  Thus, page0 and page1 would be in the returned set and it needs to account for terms that are not in the set. Now, I keep getting too many values error when I run this:

```
term = {"dog", "cat", "fish", "rat", "frog", "goat"}

def searchPages(term):
    createPageDict(d)
    for i in term:
        if i in createPageDict(d).key:
            return createPageDict(d).value

searchPages(term)
```

My idea is to create a for loop that iterates through the dictionary, but it doesn't return what I need it to. Any thoughts?